# Projecting a component inside a dynamic component

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components, angular-content-projection

I can create a component dynamically and project some template inside it just fine with the following code -

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'dynamic',
    template: `
        <p>Dynamic Component</p>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    `
})
export class DynamicComponent { }

@Component({
    selector: 'tester',
    template: `
        <p>Tester Component</p>
        <ng-container #cnt></ng-container>
        <ng-template #tpl>
            <p>[Projected Content]</p>
        </ng-template>
    `
})
export class TesterComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild('cnt', { read: ViewContainerRef }) cnt: ViewContainerRef
    @ViewChild('tpl') tpl: TemplateRef<any>

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        let content = [this.tpl.createEmbeddedView(null).rootNodes];
        this.cnt.createComponent(DynamicComponent, { projectableNodes: content });
    }
}
```

But I want to project another component (e.g. the following one) inside the dynamic component -

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'content',
    template: `<p>Content Component</p>`
})
export class ContentComponent { }
```

so that the resulting output becomes the equivalent of -

```html
<p>Tester Component</p>
<dynamic>
    <content></content>
</dynamic>
```

Cannot figure out how to achieve that. Any help/suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UPDATE

We can use the `createComponent` API to dynamically create the component and then using `contentRef.location.nativeElement` project the content onto the dynamic created component, note the double array syntax, that got this working!

test.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  ViewChild,
  TemplateRef,
  ViewContainerRef,
  ContentChild,
  createComponent,
  Injector,
  inject,
  ElementRef,
  EnvironmentInjector,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
      <p>Dynamic Component</p>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
  `,
})
export class DynamicComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'tester',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
      <p>Tester Component</p>
      <ng-container #cnt></ng-container>
      <ng-template #tpl>
          <p>[Projected Content]</p>
      </ng-template>
  `,
})
export class TesterComponent {
  @ViewChild('cnt', { read: ViewContainerRef }) cnt!: ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild('tpl') tpl!: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ContentChild('content') contentChild!: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(
    private injector: EnvironmentInjector,
    private elementRef: ElementRef
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const elementInjector = Injector.create({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: 'MyToken',
          useValue: 'Token',
        },
      ],
    });

    const contentRef = createComponent(ContentComponent, {
      environmentInjector: this.injector,
      elementInjector,
    });
    this.cnt.createComponent(DynamicComponent, {
      projectableNodes: [[contentRef.location.nativeElement]] as any,
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  standalone: true,
  template: `<p>Content Component</p>`,
})
export class ContentComponent {}
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kxylrs?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Ftest.ts,src%2Fmain.ts&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter)

---

We can just access the content using `ContentChild` and then using a or condition, we can either use the content child, or use the view child, whichever is present in the defined order!

ts

```
import {
  Component,
  ViewChild,
  TemplateRef,
  ViewContainerRef,
  ContentChild,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
      <p>Dynamic Component</p>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
  `,
})
export class DynamicComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'tester',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
      <p>Tester Component</p>
      <ng-container #cnt></ng-container>
      <ng-template #tpl>
          <p>[Projected Content]</p>
      </ng-template>
  `,
})
export class TesterComponent {
  @ViewChild('cnt', { read: ViewContainerRef }) cnt!: ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild('tpl') tpl!: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ContentChild('content') contentChild!: TemplateRef<any>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log('content', this.tpl);
    console.log(this.contentChild);
    this.cnt.createComponent(DynamicComponent, {
      projectableNodes: [
        this.contentChild?.createEmbeddedView(null)?.rootNodes ||
          this.tpl?.createEmbeddedView(null)?.rootNodes,
      ],
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  standalone: true,
  template: `<p>Content Component</p>`,
})
export class ContentComponent {}
```

main.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { ContentComponent, DynamicComponent, TesterComponent } from './test';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [DynamicComponent, TesterComponent, ContentComponent],
  template: `
    <tester/>
    <tester>
      <ng-template #content>
        <app-content/>
      </ng-template>
    </tester>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kxylrs?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Ftest.ts,src%2Fmain.ts&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Sorry if I failed to make it clear enough. I'm trying to dynamically create the `DynamicComponent` from within the `TesterComponent`, and project the `ContentComponent` inside the `DynamicComponent`, programmatically, just like I can project a template (`#tpl` in the example). The `ContentComponent`, (it's selector) is not present/embedded in any component's template.

Comment: I too looked for a way to create a `ComponentRef` from a component so I can follow this approach, but I didn't know the existence of `createComponent` in `@angular/core`. Looks like its a new addition from v14. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It does not work though if you enable ssr. Gives the error: 

NG0503: During serialization, Angular detected DOM nodes that were created outside of Angular context and provided as projectable nodes

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in `@angular/common`, `NgComponentOutlet`, which allows you to bring a component dynamically with `@Input()` decorator in your component and inject via Template Html

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ng-component-outlet-complete-example',
  template: ` <ng-template #ahoj>Ahoj</ng-template>
    <ng-template #svet>Svet</ng-template>
    <ng-container
      *ngComponentOutlet="
        CompleteComponent;
        inputs: myInputs;
        injector: myInjector;
        content: myContent
      "
    ></ng-container>`,
})
```

// Example taken from documentation ([ref](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet#a-simple-example))

---

###### Referências:

https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet

Comment: I know about the `NgComponentOutlet` directive approach, but I'm trying to find out if it can be done through content projection approach.